Can you install Wingware software in Ubuntu, in particular the personal version?
Can you install Wingware software in Ubuntu, in particular the personal version?

https://wingware.com/downloads/wingide-personal suggests that it is possible. However, Ubuntu makes use of python and python3, so take care when installing. Use installwatch (sudo apt install watchinstall). Make all your changes reversible, just in case.

N: Unable to locate package installwatch N: Unable to locate package watchinstall
